# Exception NO_ACTIVE_DUPLICATE_RULE in findDuplicates() call - SOAP API

Tags: apex, soap-api, duplicate-management

I'm trying out following code to find duplicate leads based on email ID:

```
    SObject[] inputSObjectArray = new SObject[1];
    // Instantiate an empty Java SObject
    SObject searchCriteria = new SObject();
    // Set its type to Lead.
    searchCriteria.setType("Lead");
    // Set Email field.
    searchCriteria.setField("Email", lead.getField("Email"));
    // Add the sObject to the input array
    inputSObjectArray[0] = searchCriteria;

    Connection.getInstance().getConnection().setDuplicateRuleHeader(false, false, false);

    FindDuplicatesResult[] callResults = null;

    try {
        callResults = Connection.getInstance().getConnection().findDuplicates(inputSObjectArray);
    } catch (ConnectionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (callResults != null && callResults.length > 0) {
        // print results
        System.out.println(callResults.length);
    }
```

But I'm getting following response from the API:

> [ UnexpectedErrorFault [ ApiFault exceptionCode = 'NO_ACTIVE_DUPLICATE_RULE' exceptionMessage = 'Configuration error: No duplicate rules are defined for the Lead object.' extendedErrorDetails = '{[0]}' ] ]

I'm using partner WSDL jar in my Java project.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I needed to create a Duplicate Rule in the SalesForce UI associated with the Leads.

I created a duplicate rule and activated it. Then I tried my same code and it worked.